Demon Kinematics: Estimating Moles converted/kWh in a (gas phase) Flow System
I have a magic demon that watches passing air and changes some of the molecules of type A to B. (It's actually a reaction, obviously, but what it specifically is probably doesn't matter for present purposes.)
I put the demon in the middle of a cylinder that is 10 cm in diameter and one meter long. That is, the demon lives half a meter down the tube, and sees all the air that passes that point.
I pass air containing A, B, and C into the tube at a flow rate of 1 m/sec, and measure the concentration of A (say in ppm) that goes in, and that comes out, using a tap sampler that is calibrated to accurately estimate ppm of A. 2 ppm of A goes in, and 1 ppm of A comes out the other end (1 sec later, although I'm running this continuously and have good measurements over long periods at both ends).
The demon requires 1 watt of continuous power to do this.
I want to estimate moles of A converted per kWh.
If it's helpful (I don't think it will be), I can vary the power going into the system (which will slow or speed up the demon), as well as change the flow rate through the tube. (Since I'm sampling, I don't think that the size of the device matters, but I could be wrong.)
If this were a closed, static system, I would measure that amount of A at t=0 sec and at t=1 hr -- say it removes 1/2 mole in that hour -- and the number would be just 1/2 mole per watt-hour, in this closed system. But even there, the reaction is, of course, concentration dependent, so that only holds for a particular starting concentration of A, and if the system is open (even if not flowing) diffusion would confuse the measurement;  With enough diffusion I would see essentially no change. I can't measure that diffusion, which is why I went to the flow system where I know the flow rate and the incoming and outgoing concentrations. But now I'm having trouble figuring out the equation. (An advantage of the flow system is that I have an infinite source of input air at 2 ppm A (in this example).
Dimensional analysis suggest that since I'm after moles/kwh and have delta-moles, kw and total time, I can calculate this straightforwardly, but I'm having trouble working the flow rate into it. I keep ending up with volume/time, but in accord with the sampling point above, I don't think that the volume should matter...?
(This is actually even more complex in reality because the demon is, in reality, not of zero-physical size, so there is a dwell time involved as well, but I can experimentally vary the dwell time and so can fold that into the equation easily, or at least more easily, I think, once I have the basic equation.)
There must be a standard way that this sort of thing is estimated.
Thanks in advance for any assistance and/or pointer to textbooks you can offer.

The flow rate matters, why do you think it does not? The total volume directly determines the total amount of A (which will be 2ppm of the total, which in a gas will be directly proportional to the volume).

@matt_black Yes, flow rate matters. The demon can capture A across any instantaneous cross-section (within reason). With the demon off I read 2 ppm at both ends at any (reasonable) flow rate. Powered on I read 1 ppm down-stream. If I, say, double the flow rate, it reads, say 1.5 ppm, because the dwell-time is shorter so the demon lets more A get by. So yes, the flow rate matters, but the instantaneous cross-section, which maps to total volume, doesn't. (I think -- definitely push back if I'm confused about this interpretation. But the experiment behaves as described.)

@matt_black Put another way, the area of the beam in a cross-section analysis of a particle beam ends up canceling so you just end up with the cross section being (the number of scattering events) over ((the beam flux) times (the duration of the observation)).

You write that after 1 sec half of A is converted and this needed 1 joule, and you want to know how much is converted in 1 hour by 1 kW so its just proportional.
